# How to use saltstack to manage different config file for different minions?

Tags: saltstack

I have two minions with httpd server managed under saltstack. `VirtualHost` based on ports need to be configured for them separately. So `/etc/httpd/conf.d/httpd-vhost.conf` is watched like this:

```
httpd:
  pkg.installed: []
  service.running:
    - require:
      - pkg: httpd
    - watch:
      - file: /etc/httpd/conf.d/httpd-vhosts.conf

/etc/httpd/conf.d/httpd-vhosts.conf:
  file.managed:
    - source: salt://webserver/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

The problem is that the two minions have their own server name and `httpd-vhost.conf` should be different like `ServerName www.example1.com` and `www.example2.com`. Saltstack `grains` module just work for .sls file not managed file. So any advice to make it work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just add `- template: jinja` to your `file.managed` and you can use grains in configuration files.

```
/etc/httpd/conf.d/httpd-vhosts.conf:
  file.managed:
    - source: salt://webserver/httpd-vhosts.conf
    - template: jinja
```

You can use grains in the sourced file like so:

```
{% if grains['id'] == 'dev' -%}
ServerName dev.example.com
{% else %}
ServerName example.com
{% endif -%}
```

It is this very feature that sold me on SaltStack.

Answer (score 1):

You could create to state files for each server where the only difference is the source line. Of course each source has the proper config. Then in top.sls you specify the correct state file for each of the web server.